# Is there a way to get Adobe Connect to work in Linux?

Tags: linux, wine

I need Adobe Connect 11 for my job, but I prefer to work at my Linux machine. Has anyone figured out a way to get Adobe Connect to run properly on Linux? (And yes, I know that winehq.com rates Adobe Connect as "garbage," but that was Connect 9 under wine 2.22, and no tests have been logged since then. Plus, I'm hopeful and will do almost anything to avoid having to return to Windows.)

I'm on Debian 10, using Wine 4.0-2. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Installed wine & faudio0 dependencies

   - Was unable to run ConnectSetup.exe
2. Installed 32-bit wine

   - Running `wine connectsetup.exe` opened install window, but the download failed
   - Running `sudo wine connectetup.exe` worked and the installer seemed to complete, but it never actually copied the installation files.
3. Installed Adobe Connect 11 on my Windows10 machine & copy/pasted the "Connect" folder to my Linux machine

   - Connect opened, but would not connect to room ("link invalid" error)
   - Also returned "missing ntlm_auth" error
4. Applied this fix: [Wine missing ntlm_auth 3.0.25](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090094/wine-missing-ntlm-auth-3-0-25), and installed winbind & dependencies

   - Running `wine connect.exe` now launches Connect without errors, and I'm able to provide a room url, but every url continues to return "link invalid" error message.

I'd appreciate any guidance, help, or suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

Adobe Connect 11.2 update this month is going to add in a fix to join meetings in any browser. In the meantime, you can force the browser to connect by adding at the end of the meeting URL:

```
?html-view=true
```

Comment: This requires you to get the session link using a Windows system in the first place ... since some genius over at Adobe decided to instantly redirect you without giving you the session link, if you don't have flash player in your browser ... typical Adobe nonsense ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are redirected to a page with a url something like
`https://[domain]/system/get-player?urlPath=/[host_path]/` you can remove the first bit and add `?html-view=true`.

So it would look something like

```
https://[domain]/[host_path]?html-view=true
```

If after joining the room, you can't hear or see content, there should be a little box in the top right asking to "display media".

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that your answer is very similar to the [answer by Andrew](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/632300/377345). You might want to add some explanation so that the difference in the approaches becomes clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome for Linux still contains the Flash plugin and you can use it to join Adobe Connect meetings within the browser.

Comment: [Un]fortunately, Flash has reached End-of-Life and is not supported anymore, and moreover, blocked Flash content from running in Flash Player beginning January 12, 2021,. So there must be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

1- Install [User-Agent Switcher and Manager](http://google.com/search?q=User-Agent%20Switcher%20and%20Manager) or any other "User-Agent switcher" Addon/Extension on your web browser.

2- Switch your browser's User-Agent to a Windows based one.
(e.g. if you are using Firefox on Linux, change it to Firefox on Windows; and if you are using Chrome on Linux change it to Chrome on Windows.)

[image: User-Agent Switcher and Manager]

Voila, you can now access Adobe Connect sessions through your web browser on Linux, without getting bothered by Adobe about why you don't have the already EOL Flash plugin installed!

Answer (score 0):

At the time I'm writing this, the newest version of Firefox which supports flash is version 84. Using that version of Firefox, add `?html-view=true` to the end of the URL. You can download older versions of firefox from [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) and you can disable firefox updates using [this tutorial](https://www.technipages.com/enable-disable-automatic-updates-in-firefox). In summary, that tutorial says to:

1. Select the “Menu” Menu Button button in the upper-right corner, then choose “Options“.
2. Select “General” on the left pane.
3. Scroll down to the “Firefox Updates” section.
4. Select one of the following options as desired:

   - Automatically install updates
   - Check for updates, but let me choose whether to install them
   - Never check for updates
5. Check or uncheck the “Use a background service to install updates” option as desired.